# Why is Apigility not checking authorization?

Tags: php, api, basic-authentication, laminas-api-tools

I'm using Apigility (version 1.3.2) to build an RPC-based api. I created a users.htpasswd file, then set up basic authentication as described in [this guide](https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-http-basic). From there, I went to the authorization tab each service in the API and checked the box for each method the api used.

The problem is, the api is not actually checking authorization. In other words, it's letting anyone through, authorized or no.

Is there something wrong with the authentication/authorization system in Apigility?

Edit: It seems that this problem happens as soon as you run `composer update`, which strongly suggests that doing so makes a change that breaks the built-in authentication check.

Incidentally, it also messes with the list of filters available when adding input filters to fields--only File\RenameUpload is available.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the latest composer update fixed the problem